# Cross-matching two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists where I am trying to see if there is any matches between substrings in elements in both lists.

```
["Po2311tato","Pin2231eap","Orange2231edg","add22131dfes"]
["2311","233412","2231"]
```

If any substrings in an element matches the second list such as "Po2311tato" will match with "2311".  Then I would want to put "Po2311tato" in a new list in which all elements of the first that match would be placed in the new list. So the new list would be                                        ["Po2311tato","Pin2231eap","Orange2231edg"]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the syntax `'substring' in string` to do this:

```
a = ["Po2311tato","Pin2231eap","Orange2231edg","add22131dfes"]
b = ["2311","233412","2231"]

def has_substring(word):
    for substring in b:
        if substring in word:
            return True
    return False

print filter(has_substring, a)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would think that if you are going to use the function you should also pass b to the function so it is more general

Answer (score 2):

This can be a little more concise than the jobby's answer by using a list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = ["Po2311tato","Pin2231eap","Orange2231edg","add22131dfes"]
>>> list2 = ["2311","233412","2231"]
>>> list3 = [string for string in list1 if any(substring in string for substring in list2)]
>>> list3
['Po2311tato', 'Pin2231eap', 'Orange2231edg']
```

Whether or not this is clearer / more elegant than jobby's version is a matter of taste!

Comment: What if list 2 was like this ["asd2311","asge233412","ora2231"]

Comment: Well, then list3 would come out as an empty list, as none of the members of list2 are substrings of any of the members of list1 in that case. You can easily test this stuff out yourself at the command-line interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

list1 = ["Po2311tato","Pin2231eap","Orange2231edg","add22131dfes"]
list2 = ["2311","233412","2231"]
matchlist = []

for str1 in list1:
    for str2 in list2:
        if (re.search(str2, str1)):
            matchlist.append(str1)
            break

print matchlist
```